# How can I debug VLC on Mac?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, vlc

I want to add a little feature to VLC only on Mac.

How can I build and debug it? May I use Xcode? Or I should use something different?
I download sources from github, I can see Mac OS gui module. But how can I debug it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that @feepk's answer is outdated. You can use Xcode to debug VLC on macOS.

1. Follow the [instructions](https://wiki.videolan.org/OSXCompile) to build VLC.
2. Launch the built `VLC.app`.
3. Open the Xcode project: `vlc/extras/package/macosx/VLC.xcodeproj`
4. Click Debug -> Attach to Process and choose VLC.

Comment: Is there a way to attach the debugger at the beginning of the main method? The part I want to debug is already executed by the time I do part 4)

Comment: Yes, you can set the binary to execute in the xcodeproj of VLC and ask Xcode to run VLC. This will get you the debugging environment to run from the start.
My original answer is outdated indeed and current VLC's HEAD source code allows you to use Xcode for debugging by default.

Answer (score 2):

You should use lldb on the command-line or Instruments (if appropriate). Xcode is not supported.

Additionally, get in touch with us directly on http://forum.videolan.org to get faster feedback and responses :)

Comment: So I should build VLC from sources using manual on videolan.org and attach debugger using terminal. That right?

Comment: Actually, it works quite ok with the stripped release binary, too. But yes, for full symbols, you need to compile it manually with debug enabled. Details here: http://wiki.videolan.org/OSXCompile